# SSLv3 handshake failure with mechanize under python 2.7.10, Mac OSX

Tags: python, ssl, beautifulsoup, handshake, mechanize-python

I am using mechanize in order to enter to a website. While being able to run the code on my friend's computer (whose OS is Linux), I face following handshake failure alert:

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:590)>
```

I am using the following code:

```
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import xlwt
import time
import unicodedata

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_equiv(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Chrome')]
page = br.open('https://....')
```

Comment: @Ronnie: that's completely not true. Both support SSLv3, but because SSL v3 is **completely** broken it should not be used and is disabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

SSLv3 was disabled by default, because it is **completely broken**. If possible, DO NOT use it.

> **Note:** If you find that when certain older clients or servers attempt to connect with a `SSLContext` created by this function that they get an error stating “Protocol or cipher suite mismatch”, it may be that they only support SSL3.0 which this function excludes using the `OP_NO_SSLv3`. SSL3.0 is widely considered to be completely broken. If you still wish to continue to use this function but still allow SSL 3.0 connections you can re-enable them using:
>
> ```
> ctx = ssl.create_default_context(Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
> ctx.options &= ~ssl.OP_NO_SSLv3
> ```

This is the second note here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html#ssl.create_default_context.

You will need to pass the configured SSLContext to `mechanize` somehow.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Thom. Since I am not an expert, I just want to modify and use the same connection. What is Purpose?

Comment: That's [`ssl.Purpose`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html#ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH). You will probably want to use `Purpose.SERVER_AUTH`. I have no idea how `mechanize` works, so you'll need to figure that out yourself. However, if possible I would consider contacting the people running the server and tell them they SERIOUSLY need to upgrade their shit.